# bridge two lan adapters openSuse

Tags: networking, ethernet, bridge, opensuse

On my OpenSuSe 15.1 Leap I have two lan adapters (eth0 and eth1). With eth1 I'm connected to the router and have internet access. On eth0 I want to connect a different PC such that i gets the ip from the router's dhcp.

What I tried to do:

- in YaST2 I added a ethernet bridge with DHCP active
- as the bridged adapter I added eth0 (which is the one I want to connect the second computer without internet).

When I connect the 2. computer windows is stating "identifying network" but has no access.

**What do I miss?**

PS: In the routers web UI I can see that the bridge got a different IP.

Comment: Which the OS of **2nd computer**?

Comment: Its Windows 10.

Comment: Please, run the cmd **winver** and tell us the full OS version description.

Comment: [Try disable the Windows firewall for connectivity testing by run the following cmd **netsh advfirewall set currentprofile state off**](https://www.windows-commandline.com/enable-disable-firewall-command-line/)

Comment: I don't think that is has something todo with windows. Its the same on Linux!

Comment: But you must to do so for testing purposes and to eliminate points step by step until to find the real problem.